# Page title not working in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

Below given title not appear in web page title. It shows default value.

Code:

```
public function index()
{
    $data['page_title'] = "Welcome to codigniter";
            ...................
            ...................

}
```

Comment: you have to echo `$page_tile` in between `<title></title>` tags.

Comment: Have you passing `$data` along loading view ?

Comment: For questions like this one you have/must to read tutorial -> https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/tutorial/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just pass the `$data` variable when loading the view, and then echo `$page_title` between `<title></title>` in your view.

```
<title><?php echo $page_title; ?></title>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
public function index()
{
   $data['page_title'] = "Welcome to codigniter";
        ...................
        ...................
   $this->load->view('page',$data);
}
```

**VIEW:**

```
<title><?php echo $page_title; ?> </title>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add below code in controller :

```
$this->data['title'] = 'test';
$this->load->view('folder/viewname',$this->data);
```

or You can Use

```
 $data['page_title'] = "Welcome to codigniter";
```

And access it with $title in your view file. Please check it.

mark it accepted if it works

Answer (score 0):

Yes above code will work. But only in that function only.

Every time when create controller just create some global variable so you can use everywhere. See this code:

```
class Code extends CI_Controller {
 var $TITLE = 'Welcome to codeigniter';
 function Code(){
    parent::__construct();
 }
 function index(){
   $this->load->view('page');
 }
}
```

And when you call that controller, you can be use that variable anywhere in controller, model or view which is connected to that controller. Like this:

```
echo $this->TITLE;
```